# How to set Scrapy settings?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I was reading through the scrapy docs at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html but am confused about the "Designating the Settings" section. Could someone describe in plain english how to go about implementing settings? I originally assumed it was just about making a modification to settings.py but that doesn't seem to be the case. I am trying to do a download delay as I am getting blocked from the site I am scraping. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the description is a bit confusing but you were right: *settings.py* is the right file to add the settings. However there are two settings which work parallel:

`DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`. For the latter the default value is **8**. So I would override both and it should work.

To read more about some default concurrent settings refer to the docs:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests